# Connect to a Server using a internet which requires proxy on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, server, proxy

I am trying to connect to a server. First I used ssh to connect to a server using my mobile data, it worked fine. But now I have to use an internet provided by my college which requires proxy, but I am not able to connect the server. I have already set proxy for computer and for the terminal as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is really not enough information provided here to be helpful. Can you provide more specific details on what you have tried and what is going wrong (do you get an error message)?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu in Virtual Machine, and I am using wifi provided by my college in which I have to use proxy. Now from Ubuntu, I am trying to connect a server created by my friend which he created using zerotier. Now I am sending request of  "zerotier-cli join friends_id". Though request is being completed and connection is being made. But my ip address is not showing there on zerotier. That's why I am not able to log in into the  server further.Hope it helps